# creating levels with same code in sprite kit game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, levels

I am making a sprite kit game, and I am kind of a beginner in iOS development. In my game, I am using 1 `SKScene` as 1 level. Each level will have increased difficulty from the previous level. By making multiple `SKScenes`, I have noticed that I have to reuse the code of previous levels again and again with minor changes to raise the difficulty. Isn't there a better way to do this rather than creating multiple scenes and copying the same code again and again? Is there a way to reuse the repeated code? If I want to create many levels, this would become cumbersome, and seems to reflect a bad design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And thus the theory of object oriented programming came forth, in your case specially inheritance.
OOP is specially used when we have to reuse a code over and over again,
We just inherit the class and then we can call its methods in that subclass, or even overwrite or overload the methods according to our own will.

Please check out documentations as to how inheritance takes place.
In objective c u can inherit a class by

```
 @interface 
 yourclassName : superclassName
```

syntax

Comment: that means if i implement 1 SKScene with the common code and then make it a superclass for rest of the scenes, this would work? right?

Comment: yes it would, but u need to call the methods in your subclass, and do changes accordingly if u want, calling the method itself would work

Comment: Actually look up data-driven design. Ideally one would use a single class (or set of classes) not subclasses because the differences in levels is largely in the data, not the code.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D That is worthy of being an answer as opposed to comment.

Answer (score 3):

How about subclassing an SKScene as a level. Then you can initialize the SKScene.

class.h

```
@interface 
myLevel :SKScene

-initWithYourDifferentLevelProperties:(NSInteger *)levelNumber;
```

class.m

```
@implementation

-initWithYourDifferentLevelProperties: (NSInteger *)levelNumber {

numberOfMonsters = levelNumber

}
```

Hope this helps.